# Inheritance in Java subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to write a class(SalaryEmployee) and subclass(ComissionEmployee) but I'm not getting the right salary in the main and I could not do a se1.setSalesAmount(20000). Where did I go wrong?

This is what is in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SalaryEmployee se1 = new CommissionEmployee("E3", "John", 10000);  
    se1.setSalesAmount(20000) // not found
    System.out.println(se1.getSalary());

}
```

SalaryEmployee which has id (String), name(String), salary(double). It has a constructor to initialise the instance variables. It has a `getSalary` method that returns the salary as well as a `toString` method that returns the values of the instance variables.

```
public class SalaryEmployee  {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    double salary;

    public SalaryEmployee(String id, String name, double salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "ID=" + id + " Name=" + name + " Salary=" + salary;
    }
}
```

Then in ComissionEmployee I need to write it as a subclass of SalaryEmployee which has id(String), name(String), baseSalary(double), salesAmount(double). It has a constructor to initialise id, name and baseSalary only. It has get/set methods for salesAmount. It has a getSalary method that returns the salary based on the baseSalary + commission as follows:

salesAmount below 10,000 - No commission,
at least 10,000 but below 20,000 - 3% of baseSalary,
at least 20,000 - 5% of baseSalary

```
public class CommissionEmployee extends SalaryEmployee {

    private double baseSalary;
    private double salesAmount;

    public CommissionEmployee(String id, String name, double salary) {
        super(id, name, salary);
        this.baseSalary = salary;

    }

    public void setSalesAmount(double amount) {
        this.salesAmount = amount;
    }

    public double getSalesAmount() {
        return salesAmount;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        if (salesAmount <= 10000 || salesAmount < 20000) {
            return 1.03 * baseSalary;
        } else if (salesAmount > 20000) {
            return 1.05 * baseSalary;
        } else if (salesAmount < 10000) {
            return baseSalary;
        }
        return baseSalary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us your expected results VS results obtained? Telling us the result is wrong is one thing, telling us what that result was is another.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SalaryEmployee se1 = new CommissionEmployee("E3", "John", 10000);
```

Do

```
CommissionEmployee se1 = new CommissionEmployee("E3", "John", 10000);
```

Method `setSalesAmount` is only avaiable to CommissionEmployee and it not in parent class SalaryEmployee. So this method is specific to child and only available to it. In addition to above, your condition's seems invalid. You should do something like:

```
if (salesAmount == 0) {
   return baseSalary;
} else if (salesAmount < 20000) {
   return  1.2 * baseSalary;
} else if (salesAmount >= 20000) {
    return 1.05 * baseSalary;
}
```

Comment: I tried your method but if i dont do setSalesAmount, it is returning as 10300, how can i return the original salary since no sales amount is set?

Comment: updated the answer. There seems duplicate if conditions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You created se1 as `SalaryEmployee` type which doesn't have `setSalesAmount()` method.
So,you need to downcast your se1 to CommissionEmployee:

```
((CommissionEmployee)se1).setSalesAmount(20000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `se1` still has its base type `SalaryEmployee` where `setSalesAmount` method does not exist.

I would say your program is badly designed.

Answer (score 0):

With inheritance and for that matter with interfaces the left had side of the assignment is the reference based on which the methods are resolved at compile time.so when you say

```
SalaryEmployee se1 = new CommissionEmployee("E3", "John", 10000);
se1.setSalesAmount(20000);
```

the compiler will try to find `setSalesAmount` method on the reference type i.e: SalaryEmployee and not on the instance type i.e: CommissionEmployee

At runtime when you code executes the methods are executed on the instance to which the reference points to i.e: instance of CommissionEmployee and thus it will pick the `setSalesAmount` of the subclass to execute.

Now to fix your problemthere are two way to do it:

- Either you do 
  CommissionEmployee se1 = new CommissionEmployee("E3", "John", 10000);
  se1..setSalesAmount(20000);
  but thats not inheritence being used in pure Java philosophy. So te correct way is:
- Include a `setSalesAmount` method in your superclass as well with a default implementation.
- Or even better include an abstract method `setSalesAmount` in super class if you are never going to create an instance of SalaryEmployee  directly i.e: never going to do new SalaryEmployee() anywhere as abstract classes cannot be instantiated on their own.

hope this helps.