# Calling inherited class function but still function of parent class gets executed

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

package test;

public class TestMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal cat = new Cat();
    cat.xyz();
}
```

}

```
class Animal{
    public static void xyz(){System.out.println("Inside animal");}
}

class Cat extends Animal{
    public static void xyz(){System.out.println("Inside cat");}
}
```

Output: Inside animal

[ here ideally xyz() of Cat class should have been executed but its not happening. Instead xyz() of Animal class is being executed. It only happens when I am making this xyz() function static, otherwise it's fine. ]
Please explain the reason.

Comment: your question is similar to [this question][1] Check my [answer there][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345510/inheritance-in-java-subclass/27345630
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345510/inheritance-in-java-subclass/27345630#27345630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you are using `static` methods, and `static` methods are called for the type of reference. It is not method overriding as overriding applies to instance methods and not to static methods.

If you make your method non-static then `xyz` method will be called depending on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. instances are created only during run-time i.e after the execution of the static methods. So when at the time of calling of xyz() the variable cat is still a animal   not a cat. If at all you want the desired result do one of the following:

1. Remove the static keyword from the method signature.

or

2. call the method xyz() like the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Animal cat = new Cat(); // remove this line
Cat.xyz(); // you can call static methods directly using the class name.
}
```